# how to show total number of feeds posted by category in aggregate form and send notification of total new feeds to users

Tags: python, aggregate, getstream-io

When a category posted many feeds , a notification should be sent to the users who are following category in aggregated form like on FB, Instagram that 'User' has posted 20 new feeds.

Answer (score 0):

this is standard behavior in Stream. You can find a great example here: https://getstream.io/docs/#notification-system